# Building future date array

Tags: php

I am building an interactive web form where after user logs in, they can choose to pay toward their account...either every (n)th day of the month OR every 'n' number of days - and they will choose how many payments they'd like to do

They will use datepicker to choose their starting date (which can never be sooner than tomorrow) 
I want to pass these parameters to a php script and then render a page that says they have agreed to make x number of payments on the following dates....

I'm having a problem getting the math right that I pass to this script.
i.e. if they choose to make 6 payments every 14 days starting on 6/25/2017 for example....how do I put this in an array and have the resulting page say: you've agreed to pay x amount on:

```
06/25/2017
07/09/2017
07/23/2017
08/06/2017
08/20/2017
09/03/2017 
etc
```

They can choose a minimum of 1 payment date or up to a max of 12 payment dates. Can someone steer me in the right direction on building the array?

Comment: Welcome to [so]! At this site you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Answer (score 0):

You should add x days to your inicial date, one way is:

```
$next = date("Y-m-d", strtotime('+ 14 days', strtotime($initialdate)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot...

```
<?php
  // the date the user selected
  $selectedPaymentDate = strtotime('2017-06-24');

  // the frequency a user will pay
  $freqNum = 14;
  $freqType = 'days'; // days, months, years, whatever `strtotime` will handle

  // the total number of payments a user must make
  $totalPayments = 6;

  // where we'll keep the dates
  $paymentDates = [];

  // build the dates array
  for($i = 0; $i <= $totalPayments; $i++){
      $next = ($freqNum * $i);
      $paymentDates[]= date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+{$next} {$freqType}", $selectedPaymentDate));
  }
```

Comment: So then I would just echo out each $I result?

Comment: I ran this using   echo "<pre>";
  print_r($paymentDates);      but it came back with 7 payment dates starting on 2017-06-24     Array
(
    [0] => 2017-06-24
    [1] => 2017-07-08
    [2] => 2017-07-22
    [3] => 2017-08-05
    [4] => 2017-08-19
    [5] => 2017-09-02
    [6] => 2017-09-16
)

Comment: Ok I'm making some progress...keep you posted

Comment: looking forward to hearing your solution!